# How do I decrypt the following hash from a sqlmap output?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, sqlmap

These are outputs for data in column Password from a table.

```
09630c2f8c3eb76a0c9e4f937bccae58
033b06ca049426c24789e2cb5c53a25d
```

How do I decrypt this given that I've ran it through different hash decrypting programs and keep getting an error?  What kind of hash is this? (MD5, etc...)?

I've used python /usr/bin/findmyhash and different online hash decrypting sites.  I tried hashcat but totally unfamiliar with it and would need to study it.

qlmap -u  https://fake-site informationschema fakesite -T tq_user -C password --dump

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about cryptography, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

hashes can't be decrypted first. It's one-way crypting.
And this is NOT a MD5, so long, maybe sha256.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> 09630c2f8c3eb76a0c9e4f937bccae58 = yr%Qj1n5w6G

Comment: 033b06ca049426c24789e2cb5c53a25d = zxx321654XXZ

Comment: dont hear from people who said is inposible all thing is possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Those are two strings of hex digits, 32 characters in length. That's the length of an MD5 hash, so it might be the result of MD5. Using MD5 is not recommended for password hashing, but some people have used it in the past.

But I agree with the answer from @Capibar -- hashes are one-way, not reversible.

Comment: So if it’s not reversible then how am I supposed to get a human-readable output? Maybe I should change my question. How do I use sqlmap or any sql injection program in such a way that when I get a table with example columns UserName and Password, I am able to see what the passwords are from the string of hex digits?

Comment: Why do you need to see the passwords? If the login query is vulnerable to SQL injection, you don't need to know a password to bypass the security.

Comment: If you're studying digital security, one thing you need to learn is that encryption and hashing are two different things. Encryption can be reversed. Hashing cannot be reversed. You can hash a new input, and compare that to the MD5 hash string stored in the database to see if the two hashes match. But you don't know for sure that the hash in the database was generated from the same input. A given hash string can be the result of hashing many different inputs.

Comment: Ok these answers are helping me understand more. 1) how would I go about coming up with a new hash input to compare it to the database’s? 2) if the query is vulnerable to SQL injection, then what is the next step after I get my table of logins and table of password hex digits?  Like if the passwords in the table don’t do me any good in the form they’re in, what next?

Comment: I think you need to learn how login systems work under normal conditions before you learn how to hack them.